# using an alias name for hash key value

Tags: ruby, hash

I have some json data that I receive and that I `JSON.parse` to a hash. The hash key names are integer strings like `data["0"]`, `data["1"]`, `data["2"]`, etc... where each value correspond to a state. Like 0 => START, 1 => STOP, 2 => RESTART.

I can't change the source json data to make the key more readable. Each hash will have 5 pairs that correspond to 5 different states.

I was wondering if there was a nice way for me to alias the numbers as meaningful names so when referencing the hash key value I don't have to use the number.

At the moment I'm using constants like below, but was thinking there might be a nicer, more Ruby way. Use another hash or struct so I can use `data[STATES.start]` or something?

```
STATE_START     =       "0"
STATE_STOP      =       "1"
STATE_RESTART   =       "2"

data = JSON.parse value
puts data[STATE_START]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think constants are fine. But if you want to rubify this code a bit, you can, for example, wrap the source hash in an object that will translate method names.

```
class MyHash
  def initialize(hash)
    @hash = hash
  end

  MAPPING = {
    start:   '0',
    stop:    '1',
    restart: '2',
  }

  # dynamically define methods like
  #
  # def start
  #   @hash['0']
  # end
  #
  # or you can use method_missing  
  MAPPING.each do |method_name, hash_key|
    define_method method_name do
      @hash[hash_key]
    end
  end
end

mh = MyHash.new({'0' => 'foo', '1' => 'bar'})

mh.start # => "foo"
mh.stop # => "bar"
```